# Disable POSITIVE_BUTTON ("Continue") for 5 secs

Tags: android, button, timeout, visibility, android-alertdialog

I have a alert pop-up which i show when my app launches. I want the user to read through it, so i want to grey out the continue button for 5 secs, then enable it so the user can continue.

```
 if (alertDialog == null) {
     alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setPositiveButton("Continue",
                    new AlertDialog.OnClickListener() {
                         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                             //continue with the app
                         }
                    }).create();
                    alertDialog.setTitle("My Title");
                    alertDialog.setView(myView);
                }
                if ((!alertDialog.isShowing())) {
                    alertDialog.show();
                    alertDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setEnabled(false);
                }
```

After setting the button to false, i'm unable to set it back to true. I tried using Thread.sleep(5000l) and creating my own dialog. Niether of them worked. How can i go about achieving my objective?

Thanks,
AkasH

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The UI elements are all rendered in one go after the callback from the user code has finished. This is why just adding a delay does not help.

You may want to start a thread or an `AsyncTask` where the `doInBackground` method is counting down (probably in a loop, so you can show a counter in the ok field) and then in `onPostExecute` enable the button

Pseudo-code:

```
MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask {
   doInBackground() {
      for (int i = 5; i > 0 ; i ++) {
          publishProgress (i );
          Thread.sleep(1000);
      }
   }

   onProgressUpdate(int i ) {
        okButton.setText(i);
   }

   onPostExecute() {
       okButton.setText("Ok");
       okButton.enable();
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that is working like a charm. However, is there any way to execute the AsyncTask multiple times? This works fine when user launches the game, he reads the pop-up. But in between if he comes to main-menu and launches the game again (without actually exiting the game), the continue button is shown directly. If i call the myAsyncTask.execute() in onClick method, it throws exception saying (Task can be done only once). Is there any way to run the task multiple times? Thanks

Comment: Yes, just create a new MyAsyncTask each time:  `new MyAyncTask().execute();`

Comment: ahh nevermind solved it, instead of calling new MyAsyncTask().execute, i was calling it from an instance. So, its all good and fixed now. Thanks a lot Heiko.

Comment: ahh didn't refresh the page too, my bad. Ended up doing the same thing.